# Is possible to invoke webhook in certain files (Include/exclude) on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, tekton-pipelines

I have two webhook (A, B) on the same repository that will invoke two external pipelines.
What I expect is if a specific file [`sampleB.txt`] changes, only webhook `B` will be invoked.

The issue is: the Bitbucket webhook message payload does not send the files changed.
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The [BitBucket repository event payload](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/event-payloads/#Repository-events) for a push include information about the commits pushed.

And you can use [GET /repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/diff/{spec}](https://www.any-api.com/bitbucket_org/bitbucket_org/docs/commits/_repositories_username_repo_slug_diff_spec_/GET) to get raw, git-style diff for either a single commit (diffed against its first parent)

Your listener should call a script which will process the webhook payload.

The payload will contain information about the commit, such as the commit hash.

- Use the Bitbucket API to fetch the raw, git-style diff for the given commit using the following endpoint:

  GET [https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/diff/{commit_hash}](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/diff/%7Bcommit_hash%7D)
- Parse the raw diff response to extract the list of changed files. The diff lines starting with '`diff --git`' contain the file paths.
  For example, a line like this:

  ```
  diff --git a/sampleA.txt b/sampleA.txt
  ```

  Indicates that '`sampleA.txt`' is one of the changed files.
- Iterate through the list of changed files and check if '`sampleB.txt`' is present.

  If '`sampleB.txt`' is present in the list of changed files, conditionally trigger the pipeline associated with `webhook B`.
  If not, proceed with the pipeline associated with webhook A or skip the pipeline execution as per your requirement.